# Unable to apply changes after the regex works (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell

Hello all and thanks in advance for the help!
My objective is to iterate through a bilingual XLF file and detect URLS with underscores in the trans-unit source, then replace them with '%95' so a filter in another tool works.
I cannot change the filter of the other tool btw.

I know that my regex works and finds the URLS with underscores-> ((https?://\S*?)_([^)\s]*?))

But I cannot make my code do the replacement of all the underscores in the URLs.

```
function ReplaceUnderscoresInURLs($xlfContent) {
    foreach ($transUnit in $xlfContent.xliff.file.body.'trans-unit') {
        $sourceNode = $transUnit.source

        
        $matches = [regex]::Matches($sourceNode.InnerXml, '\((https?://[^\s"]*?)_([^)\s]*?)\)')

        foreach ($match in $matches) {
            $matchedLink = $match.Groups[0].Value

            
            $matchedLinkReplaced = $matchedLink -replace '_', '%95'

           
            $sourceNode.InnerXml = $sourceNode.InnerXml -replace [regex]::Escape($matchedLink), $matchedLinkReplaced
        }
    }

    return $xlfContent
}
```

I tried to do groups, and tried different regex, but it was obvious to me that the regex was working.
I have also tried this simplified approach, but it deletes everything in the URL before the first underscore:

```
function ReplaceUnderscoresInParentheses($xlfContent) {
    $xlfContent = $xlfContent -replace '(?<=\()\S*_(?=\S*?\))', '%95'
    return $xlfContent
}
```

Sample file, same structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1" version="1.2">
    <file source-language="en-GB" target-language="el-GR" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="1">
                <source>Lorem Ipsum 1</source>
                <seg-source>
                    <mrk mtype="seg" mid="1">Lorem Ipsum 1</mrk>
                </seg-source>
                <target state="translated">
                    <mrk mtype="seg" mid="1">Λόρεμ Ίπσουμ 1</mrk>
                </target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="2">
                <source>Lorem Ipsum 2</source>
                <seg-source>
                    <mrk mtype="seg" mid="2">Lorem Ipsum 2</mrk>
                </seg-source>
                <target state="translated">
                    <mrk mtype="seg" mid="2">Λόρεμ Ίπσουμ 2</mrk>
                </target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="3">
                <source>Lorem Ipsum 3 with [Link](https://example.com/with_underscore)</source>
                <seg-source>
                    <mrk mtype="seg" mid="3">Lorem Ipsum 3 [Link](https://example.com/with_underscore)</mrk>
                </seg-source>
                <target state="translated">
                    <mrk mtype="seg" mid="3">Λόρεμ Ίπσουμ 3 [Σύνδεσμο](https://example.com/with_underscore)</mrk>
                </target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="4">
                <source>Lorem Ipsum 4 with [Another Link](https://example.com/with_underscore)</source>
                <seg-source>
                    <mrk mtype="seg" mid="4">Lorem Ipsum 4[Link](https://example.com/with_underscore)</mrk>
                </seg-source>
                <target state="translated">
                    <mrk mtype="seg" mid="4">Λόρεμ Ίπσουμ 4 [Σύνδεσμο](https://example.com/with_underscore)</mrk>
                </target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but the $sourceNode object exists on its own. Changing this object does not mean changing the values in $xlfContent. If it were a hashtable, then it would work like this foreach ($key in $hashtable.keys) {$hashtable.$key = ...}

Comment: Hard to tell what goes wrong without sample input XML to reproduce the issue with.

Comment: @rinatgadeev thanks for the tip, you are right. At this point I think that I have overcomplicate it and I am trying something really simple: function ReplaceUnderscoresInParentheses($xlfContent) {
    $xlfContent = $xlfContent -replace '(?<=\()\S*_(?=\S*?\))', '%95'
    return $xlfContent
} but the issue is that it deletes everything in the URL before the first underscore

Comment: Once again: show us some sample input data with which this behavior occurs

Comment: Sorry @MathiasR.Jessen thanks for the patience, edited with sample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use XPath to discover the relevant leaf nodes:

```
$xlfContent = [xml](Get-Content path\to\xlfFile.xml)
$nodesWithLinks = $xlfContent.SelectNodes('//*[contains(text(), "(https:")]')
```

Then use `[Regex]::Replace` to replace each url with a version of itself that has the `_`'s replaced:

```
foreach ($node in $nodesWithLinks) {
  $node.InnerText = [regex]::Replace($node.InnerText, '\(https:[^\)]+\)', {param($matchedLink) $matchedLink.Value.Replace('_', '%95')})
}
$xlfContent.Save((Join-Path $PWD "output.xml"))
```

Comment: Tried this as: function ReplaceUnderscoresInURLs($xlfContent) {
    foreach ($transUnit in $xlfContent.xliff.file.body.'trans-unit') {
        $nodesWithLinks = $xlfContent.SelectNodes('//*[contains(text(), "(https:")]')

        foreach ($node in $nodesWithLinks) {
            $node.InnerText = [regex]::Replace($node.InnerText, '\(https:[^\)]+\)', { param($node) $node.Value.Replace('_', '%95') })
        }
    }

    return $xlfContent
}  but it is still not making any changes

Comment: @Hateforms Why are you nesting it in another loop that you never use for anything? Please just try what I suggested. All the code you need is in the answer